# Custom ControlTemplate displaying words "ControlTemplate"

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to modify the ControlTemplate of CheckBox.  I got the default template from ExpressionBlend and dropped it into a CheckBox.

Why does it now display the text "System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate" next to the CheckBox?

[image]

```
     <CheckBox IsChecked="True">
<!-- the following is from ExpressionBlend -->
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOn">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOff">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedTrue">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedFalse">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="IndeterminateOn">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="IndeterminateOff">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="FocussedOn">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentFocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="FocussedOff">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentFocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" x:Name="bulletDecorator">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Grid Width="16" Height="16">
                                <Rectangle Height="14" Margin="1" x:Name="Background" 
                                   Width="14" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                   Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                   StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                                <Rectangle Height="14" Margin="1" x:Name="BackgroundOverlay" 
                                   Width="14" Opacity="0" Fill="{x:Null}" 
                                   Stroke="{StaticResource HoverBrush}" 
                                   StrokeThickness="2" />
                                <Rectangle Height="16" x:Name="PressedRectangle" 
                                   Width="16" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" 
                                   Stroke="{StaticResource HoverBrush}" 
                                   StrokeThickness="1" />
                                <Path Height="10" Margin="1,1,0,1.5" x:Name="CheckIcon" 
                              Width="10.5" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" 
                              Stretch="Fill" 
                              Data="M102.03442,598.79645 L105.22962,597.78918 L106.78825,600.42358 C106.78825,600.42358 108.51028,595.74304 110.21724,593.60419 C112.00967,591.35822 114.89314,591.42316 114.89314,591.42316 C114.89314,591.42316 112.67844,593.42645 111.93174,594.44464 C110.7449,596.06293 107.15683,604.13837 107.15683,604.13837 z" />
                                <Rectangle Height="8" x:Name="IndeterminateIcon" 
                                   Width="10" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" />
                                <Rectangle Height="14" x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" 
                                   Width="14" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Rectangle Height="16" x:Name="ContentFocusVisualElement" 
                                   Width="16" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" 
                                   Stroke="{StaticResource HoverShineBrush}" 
                                   StrokeThickness="1" />
                                <Rectangle Height="12" x:Name="ShineRectangle" 
                                   Width="14" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="1" 
                                   Stroke="{x:Null}" 
                                   StrokeThickness="1" 
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ShineBrush}" 
                                   Margin="2,2,2,2" />
                            </Grid>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                  Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FocussedOff}" 
                                         x:Name="FocussedOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FocussedOn}" 
                                         x:Name="FocussedOn_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsThreeState" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ThreeStateOn_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedFalse}" />
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ThreeStateOff_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedTrue}" />
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                <Condition Property="IsThreeState" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ThreeStateOn1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource IndeterminateOn}" />
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ThreeStateOff1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource IndeterminateOff}" />
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="CheckIcon" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedFalse}" 
                                         x:Name="CheckedTrue_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CheckedTrue_BeginStoryboard1" Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedTrue}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Background" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}" TargetName="Background" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="bulletDecorator" Value="0.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>


            </CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you assign `ControlTemplate` as a value of `CheckBox`. You should assign it to the `Template` property:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="True">
    <CheckBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            ...
        </ControlTemplate>
    </CheckBox.Template>
</CheckBox>
```